# Typescript - RequireJS specify pathing in require.config

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript

I am creating a new set of web pages in an existing application. We are beginning to implement Typescript+RequireJS.

I am trying to figure out how I can do a require call in typescript that uses a name rather than a path. All the pathing will be specified in the require.config

As an example here is my main.ts

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/Scripts/Modules',
    paths: {
    'baseObject' : 'objects/base',
    'inheritedObject' : 'objects/some/other/paths/inheritedObject'
});
```

Here is baseObject.ts:

```
 class BaseObject {
    initialize(): void {

    }

    fingerprint: string;
}
export = BaseObject;
```

Now what I would like to do in inheritedObject.ts is something like:

```
import baseObj = require('baseObject');
class InheritedObject extends baseObj{
  //Object full of stuff
}
```

Since I am specifying the pathing in the require.config, I don't want it in the require call. How can I get Typescript to work using just the string(not the path!) provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. Here is what I did(take special note of the file name vs the class name.):

```
File: /Objects/baseObject.ts
class BaseObject {
    initialize(): void {

    }

    fingerprint: string;
}
export = BaseObject;
```

Next we have:

```
File:/Objects/Objects.d.ts
import baseObjInstance = require("baseObject");
export module "baseObject"{
   export = baseObjInstance;
}
```

and the implementation:

```
File:/Controllers/baseController.ts

import baseObj = require('baseObject');
class BaseController extends baseObj{
}
export = BaseController;
```

It seems that this allows a definition to be registered so typescript understands the definition when you `require('baseObject')`. I believe that my require statements are pathing, they are just doing it to the local directory. And that allows me to specify my pathing in the require config, I just have to be sure to match the module export statements casing in the require config. I.E.

```
    require.config({
       paths: {
        "baseObject": 'Objects/baseObject'
    }
})
```

The only downside is that I have to add an export statement per object definition.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to figure out how I can do a require call in typescript that uses a name rather than a path

`import baseObj = require('baseObject');` will not work at the moment (disclaimer: *if you do not want to manually create a `.d.ts`*). You must use relative paths. Your IDE can help : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript#relative-paths

Note: Such base path based resolution is coming soon : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2338